# Visualforce Help

Tags: visualforce, community

I'm looking to built a visualforce page that will display output text box1 when button1 is clicked.  If the user clicks button2, then the output  text box2 will be display in the same location as text box1.  In other word, text text box1 will disappear and text box2 will be shown in the same location.  Can this be done and what do we call capability?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done and it is a combination of the `rendered` tag and described in many posts talking about `Partial Page Refresh` along with custom controllers